# Zeroes of global section and degree of a line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface and $K$ be the canonical bundle. Consider $D = p_1 + p_2 + .... + p_n $ a divisor on $X$. Is it true that number of zeroes of a global section of $K(D)$  is equal to deg$K(D)$ ?   where $K(D)= K \otimes \mathcal O(D)$.

I know that for the case of $K$, deg$K$= number of zeroes of a global section of $K$. Same should follow for $K(D)$.

Comment: This isn't quite true. Degree is number of zeroes minus number of poles, counted with multiplicity.

Comment: @Asvin Does it mean that a global section can have poles?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I didn't see global section. In that case there are no poles but in general a rational section can have poles.

Comment: Okay. So it's true, right. I mean number of zeroes equals to deg K(D) ?

Comment: Yes, that's right for any longer bundle. You can prove it by induction on the degree for instance.

Comment: @asvin Thank you.